# How to get customer and company data in a CSV file from MySQL?

Tags: magento2, database, sql, b2b, magento-2-commerce

I'm running a Magento Commerce Cloud B2B, and I need to get a list of these data below.

- Customer ID
- Customer Name
- Company Name
- Company User Agreement

As I can't export a file with these pieces of information above via the admin panel, how could I do it via a MySQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **MySQL INNER JOIN** to do it.
This script is going to help you with it:

```
SELECT customer_grid_flat.entity_id ,customer_grid_flat.name, customer_grid_flat.billing_company, company_erp.`is_end_user_agreement` FROM customer_grid_flat 
INNER JOIN company ON company.company_name = customer_grid_flat.billing_company
INNER JOIN company_erp ON company_erp.company_id = company.entity_id;
```

[image: Magento 2 get customer data via MySQL query]

### Export SQL

To export this into a file you can run this code snippet below with the SQL file containing the script above:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u magento -pmagento magento < customer-company-ua.sql > customer-company.csv
```

### Convert it to CSV

To convert it to CSV separated by comma, you can run this command below instead.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u magento -pmagento magento < customer-company-ua.sql | sed 's/\t/,/g' > customer-company.csv
```